# Java - Cannot find symbol constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor, program-entry-point

I'm completely new to Java, so I'm sorry if my question is dumb. Im working on this assignment, and I've been reading about main methods for hours now, but I just cant figure it out. I put some of my code below. I might be way off here, but what I'm hoping to accomplish is to get the main method to start the constructor, but when I compile I get an error saying "cannot find symbol - constructor Player". Now, Im guessing this has something to do with the string parameters of the constructor, but I'm all out. If anyone could shed some light on this, probably very simple problem, I'd be very happy :)

```
public class Player {
private String nick;
private String type;
private int health;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Player player = new Player();
    player.print();
}


public Player(String nickName, String playerType) 
{

    nick = nickName;
    type = playerType;
    health = 100;
    System.out.println("Welcome " + nick +" the " + type + ". I hope you are ready for an adventure!");
}

   public void print()
{
    System.out.println("Name: " + nick);
    System.out.println("Class: " + type);
    System.out.println("Remanining Health: " + health);
}
```

Comment: You're trying to create a `Player`, but you're not passing in a `nickName` or a `playerType`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Player` has no no-arg constructor, you could use:

```
Player player = new Player("My Nickname", "Player Type");
```

If you wish to prompt the user for the `Player` arguments, you can read like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Player Name:");
String nickName = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter Player Type:");
String playerType = scanner.nextLine();
Player player = new Player(nickName, playerType);
```

Comment: What I want to do is make the program start, and then prompt the user for a name and nick string. Wont this just name the player and class "My Nickname" and "Player Type"?

Comment: Cannot find symbol - class scanner. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to `import java.util.Scanner;`

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you are using `0-arg constructor`, when you haven't got one: -

```
Player player = new Player();
```

Note that, when you provide a parameterized constructor in your class, the compiler will not add default constructor. You would have to add one 0-arg constructor manually, if you are using it.

So, either you can add one `0-arg constructor` as such: -

```
public Player() {
    this.nick = "";
    this.type = "";
    this.health = -1;
}
```

or, use the parameterized constructor to create the object.

Comment: How can I use the parameterized constructor to create the object? Thats kinda what I was hoping to do. What I want to do is make the program start, and then prompt the user for a name and nick string, without having any values for playerType and nickName before they are entered in the strings.

Again, I'm 100% green at this, so If not making any sense, tell me :)

Comment: @JarandBoge.. Then first read the values from the user. Store it in some variable. And then use the parameterized constructor, passing those variables as parameter. That wouldn't be that difficult. It's just the way you pass string literals as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When your class explicitly defines [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), implicit no-arg constructor won't be created.

You have explicit constructor in your class

```
public Player(String nickName, String playerType) 
{

    nick = nickName;
    type = playerType;
    health = 100;
    System.out.println("Welcome " + nick +" the " + type + ". I hope you are ready for an adventure!");
}
```

And trying to invoke no-arg constructor

```
 Player player = new Player();
```

Either you need to pass parameters in above code (or) create no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A default constructor is created by java when a construtor is missing, this construtor simply calls the super class. When you defined an explicit constructor java wont create one. So you can either define one default constructor  in your class
e.g.

```
public Player() 
{   nick = "abc";
    type = "type";
    health = 100;
    System.out.println("Welcome " + nick +" the " + type + ". I hope you are ready for an adventure!");
}
```

or modify the code to call the constructor u defined.

```
 Player player = new Player("nick","type");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried to do in your `main()`-method was to create a new Player object. But the problem is that you had to use the constructor you implemented (`Player(String, String)`) but you used a constructor without any parameters (`Player()`).

You should either use empty strings (e.g. if you want to get a player dummy)

```
Player player = new Player("","");
```

or you should give the new player instance the name and type you want to, so for example

```
Player player = new Player("flashdrive2049","Player");
```

Regards.